# return URL handler for docusign connection returns 403 error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working the DocuSign API and I have an issue while trying to receive an update on how many and which users signed on my internet form. I have created Handler with SSL certificate that supposed to get information on streaming mode. but, when I'm trying to make the connection I get "forbidden 403" error.

If anyone has already experienced such a problem I will be pleased to get some assistance here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DocuSign API returning a HTTP403 forbidden basically means that the remote service did not authorize you to do the action you are attempting to do.

Comment: I know that but why the service did not authorize my action? this I cant figuring out...

Comment: Sorry, hard to tell. Maybe try to contact DocuSign support.

Comment: are you using TLS 1.0, as DocuSign has deprecated TLS1.0 support. Also have you download DocuSign SSL certificates using [DS Trust](https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/docusign-public-certificates/) link

Comment: Also can you share which API call you are making? I am not able to understand which returnURLHandler you are referring to? Also try to make same API call with POSTMAN as well.